# Angular 2 Unit tests beforeEachProvider doesn't inject the service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to test my components in Angular 2 but having problem with it when the component's service is not within its providers.

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ServiceName} from '../../services/ServiceName';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-name',
  template: `
    <div></div>
  `
})

export class ComponentName {    
  constructor(private ServiceName: ServiceName) {
  }
}
```

and this is my test:

```js
import {ComponentName} from '<path>';
import {ServiceName} from '<path>';

import {
  iit,
  it,
  ddescribe,
  describe,
  expect,
  inject,
  injectAsync,
  TestComponentBuilder,
  beforeEachProviders,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
  setBaseTestProviders
} from 'angular2/testing';

beforeEachProviders(() => [
  ServiceName
]);

import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';

setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

describe('ServiceName', () => {

  it('should have name property set', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(ComponentName).then((fixture) => {
      fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.isPanelActive = true;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('a.yes')).toContainText('Something');
    });
  }));

});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 Failed: No provider for ServiceName! (ComponentName -> ServiceName)
Error: DI Exception
```

I tried overrideProvide method, it didn't work and also tried creating a TestComponent inside the test and passing the provider there along with the ComponentName directive.

Anyone has any idea? Is it not possible to have services bootstrap'ed by bootstrap file and not use providers in @Component? I thought that was the whole point of beforeEachProviders.

Comment: Have you tried moving `beforeEachProviders() {}` into `describe('xxx', () { ...}) `?

Comment: I did, makes no difference.

Comment: `ServiceName` doesn't have any constructor parameters?

Comment: ServiceName has a constructor.

Comment: Sure, the question was whether the constructor has parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. It was System.js configuration. It wasn't giving any other error. Because so many scenarios, I am suspecting that using packages inside the config block caused it. I reconfigured my karma and test-main files following this:

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the problem? I have exactly what you had and I'm kind of stack.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in tests you need explicitly define how the Injector should instantiate a given token. Use [`provide`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/provide-function.html) function for this:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  provide(ServiceName, {useClass: ServiceName})
]);
```

Comment: Can you create minimal reproducible example (e.g. test repo on github).
because for me your code throws exactly the same error but using `provide` everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and solved it with this implementation of the `provide` function:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  return provide(ServiceName, {useClass: ServiceName})
]);
```

You need to be sure to `return` the provider or it isn't recognized.